# Best practice issue: Datatable and representation in objects

Tags: c#, .net

I need a datatable in order to display the data at a WPF datagrid augmented by some generated data.
But i also need to load the data from the database to local C# objects  because the classes that represent tha data do many calculations .

So what is better? Depend only at datatable ? Or have the data both in objects and datatable?

Comment: Best practice? Well, I haven't used `DataTable` for *years*...

Comment: If you are throwing something together, use a DataTable, if you want full control and pure execution speed, use objects - this is why @Marc hasn't used one in *forever* - using both will just take up more memory...

Comment: @davisoa - actually, I'm equally interested in maintainability etc.

Comment: Then how to show the data at the datagrid without a DataTable??

Comment: Typically I'd use a class-based model, i.e. `class Customer {...}`, and bind to a `List<Customer>` or similar. Usually involving some kind of ORM for the heavy-lifting between objects and SQL tables. To be sure, `DataTable` *will work*, but it isn't necessarily the best option.

Comment: @Marc - definitely, I should have said "this is *partly* why..."

Comment: Seems good idea to bind a List<> hope it works with wpf...

Comment: You'll probably have less trouble with enumerables of actual entities than with data table... FYI, Silverlight, WPF's little brother does not have the concept of datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may adopt  following startegy

If you maintaining two sets of data (one in data table and another in C # class objects, you need to manually synchronize data.)

What you can do is create a class which will bring all the columns which needs to show on grid than create a List of this class and bind the data in grid.

in this way , you will be able to avoid duplication of your model as well as manully synchronization between sets of data.

Comment: How to create this class? If you could a small example.. Also WPF datagrid NET 3.5 is a bit weird